# Run Docker Engine in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows, docker

I have Windows 10 Home and cannot therefore install and run the Docker Engine (without resorting to using Docker Toolbox).

I do, however, have Ubuntu running in Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Is it possible for me to run Docker Engine inside WSL on my Windows 10 Home machine?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but have you tried to google the issue?

Comment: Yes, I've googled it but did not find a definitive answer regarding WSL on Windows 10 Home. If you know the answer and post it I will gladly accept it.

Comment: With WSL 2 on Windows 10, May 2019 edition, the answer is an unequivocal yes. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518575/6309).

Comment: There is an option how to install and run the docker engine directly on Windows 10 Home (without using Docker Toolbox), check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/talon/4191def376c9fecae78815454bfe661c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, as a [blog post from MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/08/cross-post-wsl-interoperability-with-docker/) indicates:

> We frequently get asked about running docker from within the Windows
>   Subsystem for Linux (WSL). **We don’t support running the docker daemon
>   directly in WSL**. But what you can do is call in to the daemon running
>   under Windows from WSL.

Note that "The daemon running under Windows" is only possible using the Hyper-V virtualization feature which is not available in the Windows 10 Home edition.

Comment: I'm petty sure he mentioned "Docker for Windows" not working on the Home edition since it relies on some Hyper-V tech I think

Comment: Thanks @tdcc . This sort of gives me the answer as "No" though: "We don’t support running the docker daemon directly in WSL."

Comment: Ooops, missed that part. But maybe you can use a different hypervisor such as VirtualBox (see [link](https://gist.github.com/strarsis/44ded0d254066d9cb125ebbb04650d6c))

Comment: @tdcc please also note that the best practice for answers on SO is to quote the relevant bits your answer, in case the link goes dead sometime in the future.

Comment: @tdcc can you update your answer to "No" and include the quote? That way I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

the next feature update for Windows 10 will be released in the next weeks and it will finally support Docker Engine inside WSL. Well, not oficially, but I'm testing the Release Preview build 17134 and I can confirm the dockerd from docker.io that comes with Ubuntu xenial works.

I can even compile docker from source using a docker container inside WSL. 
It's great news for Windows10 Home users and also for those who don't have Vt-x support on their hardware, like my old 2008 PC.

Answer (score 1):

The [May 2019 announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/) from Microsoft (for Windows 2010, May 2019 edition) is clear ([Craig Loewen](https://twitter.com/craigaloewen)):

> ### WSL 2!
>
> Changes in this new architecture will allow for:
>
> - dramatic file system performance increases,
> - and full system call compatibility, **meaning you can run more Linux apps in WSL 2 such as Docker**.
>
> Here’s a quick demo of WSL 2 in action.
>
> When we start our distro we get access to a working bash shell in under two seconds, and can run services and apps like docker right away.
>
> To summarize: while WSL 2 does use a VM, it will be managed and run behind the scenes leaving you with the same user experience as WSL 1.

[image: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wp-content/uploads/sites/33/2019/05/runwsl.gif]

As [described here](https://itsfoss.com/windows-linux-kernel-wsl-2/) by [Abhishek Prakash](https://itsfoss.com/author/abhishek/):

> [Canonical has announced](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2019/05/06/canonical-announces-support-for-ubuntu-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2) the support for WSL 2 meaning you would be able to use Ubuntu through WSL 2.
>
> > Collaboration with Microsoft enables us to certify Ubuntu on WSL, including Docker containers, Kubernetes, and snaps.
> >     Stephan Fabel, Director of Product at Canonical

Comment: the docker service keeps stopping on my setup, can you help ?

Comment: @HarshGundecha Yes, but it is best to describe the issue in a separate question, with the exact version of your Windows, WSL, VSCode, and an illustration of the problem. That way, others can help too, and all can benefit from the resolution of said issue.